# How to reset a method mock in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, integration-testing, spock

I had a mocked bean in a configuration:

```
@Profile('test')
@Configuration
class TestSecurityConfig {
  private final mockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()
  @Primary @Bean
  AuthUserDetailsProvider authUserDetailsProvider() {
      mockFactory.Stub(AuthUserDetailsProvider)
  }
}
```

By default, I mock a method call is `setup()` method for all tests.

```
def setup() {
    authProvider.authenticationPrincipal >> random(authUserDetails)
}
```

By in a specific test, I need to override the method mock

```
def 'exercise missed user processing'() {
    given: 'no user data'
    authProvider.authenticationPrincipal >> emptyUser
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I override a method mocking in Spock?
Is there any way to reset mock interceptions manually?

Comment: Why would you want to reset a mock? Mocks are cheap, hence the name. You simply create a new mock, if you want different behaviour. It is really as simple as that. There is no need to complicate the matter. 

Comment: @kriegaex impossible ;)

Comment: @kriegaex "Why would you want to reset a mock?" - There isn't a good reason to do it, but the answer to your question is because the mock has been initialized with information that isn't appropriate for the test.  Resetting the mock isn't the way to deal with the problem, but that is the reason that the OP wants to reset a mock.

Comment: Well, the remedy for false use of mocks is not a nifty trick to work around it but to eliminate the root cause of the problem by initialising the mock correctly.

Comment: "Well, the remedy for false use of mocks is not a nifty trick to work around it but to eliminate the root cause of the problem by initialising the mock correctly." - I agree with you.  I was addressing your question.  It sounded like you wanted to know why the OP wants to do this, and I think what I described is the answer to that.

Answer (score 3):

Interactions defined in `then` blocks will have precedence over those defined in `given`/`setup`, for the preceding `when` block. Normally, you pair them with assertions, i.e., `1 * ...` but it works for plain stubbing too.

```
import spock.lang.*

class ASpec extends Specification {
  List myList = Mock()
    
  def setup() {
    myList.get(0) >> 1
  }
    
  def "default behavior"() {
    expect: 
    myList.get(0) == 1
  }
    
  def "override behavior"() {
    when:
    def result = myList.get(0)

    then:
    myList.get(0) >> 42
    result == 42
  }
}
```

So in your case:

```
def 'exercise missed user processing'() {
    when:
    ...

    then:
    1 * authProvider.authenticationPrincipal >> emptyUser
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. This is kind of mentioned in passing [here](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_where_to_declare_interactions) in the context of interactions. Good to know that it works for plain stubbing, too. Asking you as a maintainer: Is this something Spock users should rely on and even use as a tool? I can kind of see why the OP wants this, but actually it does not make the spec more readable. I would at least comment it, if using it at all.

Comment: You normally use it for combined mocking assertions with stubbing, and currently it is the only way to do this. There are some attempts to change this, but they all have other drawbacks. 
So, if you have a mock use `_ * mock.method() >> value` if you only have a stub you have to leave the interaction count out and just do `stub.method() >> value` in the `then` block.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is used for combining mocking + stubbing (or stubbing + verifying interactions), and I regularly use it for that matter. Trying to do that separately is a frequent error among Spock users, because it is so counter-intuitive. But it is documented as a caveat, so it is fine. My question was about actively using what normally is an anti-pattern in order to override peviously stubbed methods. Is this a usage pattern you would recommend or actively promote?

Comment: As the text would be to long for a comment here, I moved the discussion over to the Spock discussions https://github.com/spockframework/spock/discussions/1395

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't work?

Whatever you put in setup will be executed before each test.  If you don't want that, then the code probably shouldn't be in setup.

> How can I override a method mocking in Spock?

If by "override" you mean undo what was done in setup and then do something else, I am not aware of a way to do that.

> Is there any way to reset mock interceptions manually?

Not that I am aware of.  It is unusual to tell the mock that you want a certain behavior and later tell the mock that you have changed your mind.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @leonard-brünings is quite helpful, but I feel that it missed to explain the below part of the question with a more direct and simple explanation:

> But it doesn't work.

The [Where to Declare Interactions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_where_to_declare_interactions) section has the explanation:

> When an invocation on a mock object occurs, it is matched against interactions in the interactions' declared order. If an invocation matches multiple interactions, the earliest declared interaction that hasn’t reached its upper invocation limit will win.

Because Spock sees the interaction in `setup` before the `given:` section, what this means is that the one defined in `setup` takes precedence.

> How can I override a method mocking in Spock?

This is already explained and shown in the answer from @leonard-brünings, but just want to quote the relevant section from the same above documentation:

> There is one exception to this rule: Interactions declared in a `then:` block are matched against before any other interactions. This allows to override interactions declared in, say, a setup method with interactions declared in a `then:` block.

Which is why the solution is to move the interaction from the `given:` block to `then:` block.